# How to recursively loop through map using different data structures

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out the best way to recursively go through a `[string]int` map in Go. I'm building a game in which multiple countries are involved, and grouped together by teams of two in the end.

The goal is to match the first two countries with the lowest 'score' into its own group of two, and add it back to the collection giving the new map a total value of the scores of those countries.

Then recursively doing that to all the groups, ending up with one group and one total value in the end.

For example, if you had:

```
score := map[string]int{
        "Canada": 7,
        "US": 2,
        "Germany": 3,
        "Korea": 4,
}
```

group1 = `{[US:2] [Germany:3]}` with a total of 5

group1 would now be put back into the initial collection with a 'score' of 5 since it takes the two lowest scores. We would now have:

```
score := map[string]int{
        "Canada": 7,
        "Korea": 4,
        group1: `US:2 Germany:3` with a total of 5
}
```

If this was now the lowest score in the collection, the next iteration would be:

group2 = `{[Korea:4] [group1:5]}`

```
 score := map[string]int{
            "Canada": 7,
            group2: `Korea:4 group1:5` with a total of 9
  }
```

And so on until you're left with one.. I think the basic structure should be something like this. However, I'm unsure of the proper way to do this since the data structure is now encompassing a `[string]int` map, as well as this new map.

I realize this is not such a generic question, but could an interface be used for this? I'm very new to Go, so advice would be helpful.

Here is an example to further illustrate what I mean:
https://play.golang.org/p/cnkTc0HBY4

Comment: That's not a slice; that's a map.

Comment: You write "The goal is to match the first three countries with the lowest 'score' into its own group of three" but as far as I can see the groups contain two countries.

Comment: Wouldn't a tree structure be more appropriate than a map?

Comment: Thanks.. Sorry the three vs two is a typo. I'll update

Comment: In the example listed in the play link, there is somewhat of a tree structure. But not sure how to get this further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Silly question, but can we assume this list isn't going to be huge? As in, even an O(n^2) or even maybe O(n^3) algorithm would suffice? Trying to take some shortcuts ;)

Comment: Could you try `map[string]interface{}`? and compare the score with `type assert`？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can "easy" be solved using a [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

```
package main

import (
    "container/heap"
    "fmt"
)



// Something that has a score
type Scoreable interface {
    fmt.Stringer
    Score() int
}



// A country has a name and a score
type Country struct {
    name  string
    score int
}

// Country implements Scoreable
func (c Country) Score() int {
    return c.score
}

// ... and fmt.Stringer
func (c Country) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s [%d]", c.name, c.score)
}



// A team consists of two Scoreable's and has itself a score
type Team struct {
    team1, team2 Scoreable
    score        int
}

// Team implements Scoreable
func (t Team) Score() int {
    return t.score
}

// ... and fmt.Stringer
func (t Team) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("(%s + %s)", t.team1.String(), t.team2.String())
}



// The heap will be implemented using a slice of Scoreables
type TeamHeap []Scoreable

// TeamHeap implements heap.Interface
func (th TeamHeap) Len() int {
    return len(th)
}

func (th TeamHeap) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return th[i].Score() < th[j].Score()
}

func (th TeamHeap) Swap(i, j int) {
    th[i], th[j] = th[j], th[i]
}

func (th *TeamHeap) Push(t interface{}) {
    *th = append(*th, t.(Scoreable))
}

func (th *TeamHeap) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *th
    n := len(old)
    t := old[n-1]
    *th = old[0 : n-1]
    return t
}


// The main function
func main() {

    // Create a heap and initialize it
    teams := &TeamHeap{}
    heap.Init(teams)

    // Push the countries (NB: heap.Push(), not teams.Push())
    heap.Push(teams, Country{"Canada", 7})
    heap.Push(teams, Country{"US", 2})
    heap.Push(teams, Country{"Germany", 3})
    heap.Push(teams, Country{"Korea", 4})

    // Take the two teams with lowest score and make a new team of them
    // Repeat this until there's only one team left
    for teams.Len() > 1 {
        t1 := heap.Pop(teams).(Scoreable)
        t2 := heap.Pop(teams).(Scoreable)
        heap.Push(teams, Team{t1, t2, t1.Score() + t2.Score()})
    }

    // Print the teams that we now have in the heap
    for teams.Len() > 0 {
        t := heap.Pop(teams).(Team)
        fmt.Println(t)
    }
}
```

You can find [runnable code](https://play.golang.org/p/WI48kkU2L1) on the Go Playground.

Comment: thanks for the detailed comments. since the result will end up being a type (Team), that implements Scoreable, is there a trick to be able to iterate through them? I would like to show them as a list to my users but not sure how.

Comment: For example, iterate through the slice of Scorable, so we can see the new groups that were created md2perpe. Any ideas?

Comment: Then hopefully I can track the relation of the group to the one above them. For example, with `(Canada [7] + (Korea [4] + (US [2] + Germany [3])))` we can prove that US and Gemany is a sub group with Korea

Comment: Here I have added a printout in a simple tree structure: https://play.golang.org/p/6b8JNHrmQA

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "container/heap"
    "fmt"
)

//Recursive data structure may looks something like
type Group struct {
    Score   int
    Left    *Group
    Right   *Group
    Country string
}

//You can use slice to hold them organized in tree
type GrHeap []Group

//To implement your logic you can use stdlib/container/heap Heap interface
//you must implement Heap interface for your slice
func (h GrHeap) Len() int           { return len(h) }
func (h GrHeap) Less(i, j int) bool { return h[i].Score < h[j].Score }
func (h GrHeap) Swap(i, j int)      { h[i], h[j] = h[j], h[i] }

func (h *GrHeap) Push(x interface{}) {
    // Push and Pop use pointer receivers because they modify the slice's length,
    // not just its contents.
    *h = append(*h, x.(Group))
}

func (h *GrHeap) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *h
    n := len(old)
    x := old[n-1]
    *h = old[0 : n-1]
    return x
}

func main() {
    //you most likely already have a map
    //anyway it will be handy to keep it for convenient access to individual country
    score := map[string]int{
        "Canada":  7,
        "US":      2,
        "Germany": 3,
        "Korea":   4,
    }
    //here we allocate heap
    gr := make(GrHeap, 0)
    //populate it from map
    for k, v := range score {
        g := Group{v, nil, nil, k}
        gr = append(gr, g)
    }
    //and initialize
    heap.Init(&gr)
    //and here we use heap magic to implement your logic
    for len(gr) > 2 {
        l := heap.Pop(&gr).(Group)
        r := heap.Pop(&gr).(Group)
        ng := Group{l.Score + r.Score, &l, &r, ""}
        heap.Push(&gr, ng)
    }
    fmt.Println(gr)
    fmt.Println(gr[1].Left)
    fmt.Println(gr[1].Right.Left)
//and you can see it works https://play.golang.org/p/gugJxJb7rr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `map[string]interface{}` with `Type assertion`。
Here is the demo

```
package main

import "fmt"

const total = "total"


func GetValue(i interface{}) int {
    value, ok := i.(int)
    if ok {
        return value
    }
    return i.(map[string]interface{})[total].(int)
}

func main() {
    score := map[string]interface{}{
        "Canada":  7,
        "US":      2,
        "Germany": 3,
        "Korea":   4,
    }
    groupCount := 0

    for len(score) > 2 {
        var (
            firstMin  = math.MaxInt32
            secondMin = math.MaxInt32
            firstKey  = ""
            secondKey = ""
        )
        for k, v := range score {
            iv := GetValue(v)
            if iv < firstMin {
                secondMin = firstMin
                secondKey = firstKey
                firstMin = iv
                firstKey = k
                continue
            }
            if iv < secondMin {
                secondMin = iv
                secondKey = k
                continue
            }

        }
        groupCount++

        score[fmt.Sprintf("Group%d", groupCount)] = map[string]interface{}{
            firstKey:  score[firstKey],
            secondKey: score[secondKey],
            total:     GetValue(score[firstKey])+ GetValue(score[secondKey]),
        }
        delete(score, firstKey)
        delete(score, secondKey)
    }
    fmt.Println(score)
}
```

Here is the link https://play.golang.org/p/qq5qwAsh1m